# Ruby on Rails - HABTM assign after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm using rails 3.2.3 and am having trouble assigning a value in my HABTM relation.

Basically I have got 2 models, Product and User.
When I create a new Product, I want to insert in the Products_Users middle table the inserted values.

It has to be a HABTM as in the future I want to be able to say "user x can also edit that product", instead of just the product's original creator.

My models: (other relations omitted for simplicity)

```
product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

attr_accessible <product attributes>, :user_ids, :user_id #it says cant mass assign user_ids so I also added the :user_id, but then it says unknown attribute :user_id
end
```

---

```
user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :products
attr_accessible :user_id <plus the user attributes>
end
```

My products controller has the default actions and code from scaffolding.

The problem may also lie in my View. I also have a HABTM relation between products and categories and it as all fine (I choose the categories from a checkbox list)

But how can I insert in the Products_Users table the new line after an already logged user creates a new product?

Im trying to use in my view after in the form:

<%= f.hidden_field  :product_id, :value => params[:id]%> #What to put here if the product isn't tecnically created?

<%= f.hidden_field  :user_id, :value => current_user.id%>#This "current_user.id" works in other views.

This is not working, and makes little sense also, is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I cannot help you here but please **never ever** put the current user into form fields. It's very easy to hijack from client side.

Comment: Humm I see...but how will I know which user is creating the product? :/

Comment: Set it explicitly in the controller action where you send the form to afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I deleted the `hidden fields` and added this after the save:

```
user=current_user
@product.users << user
```

Hope it helps someone.

Regards